# Как в QML организовать запоминание предыдущего значения свойства?

Tags: qt, qml

Вопрос: каким образом в декларативном языке QML можно организовать запоминание предыдущего значения свойства?

То есть, задача состоит в том, чтобы перед любым изменением свойства запомнить его значение в другое свойство.

Проблема в том, что существующий механизм сигналов `onИмяСвойстваChanged()` испускает сигнал об изменении свойства уже после его изменения. И в этом обработчике невозможно получить предыдущее значение свойства чтобы его запомнить.

Желательно увидеть примеры кода.

----- 8< -----

UPD: Небольшое пояснение. Имеем некий тип **RibbonImage**. У него есть два пользовательских свойства: **targetDigit** и **previousDigits**.

Код, который находится "выше", задает значение **targetDigit** путем установки свойства, вот так:

```
RibbonImage {
    targetDigit: timeString.charAt(5)
}
```

Этот код ничего не знает (и не должен знать) про предыдущее значение. Значит, запоминаться предыдущее значение **targetDigit** должно в самом типе (в нашем случае в **RibbonImage**).

Отследить изменение свойства **targetDigit** в коде **RibbonImage** мы можем с помощью обработчика **onTargetDigitChanged()**. Но внутри него невозможно сохранить предыдущее значение targetDigit в свойство **previousDigits**. А невозможно потому, что это **targetDigit** в момент вызова обработчика уже новое. И не из чего получить предыдущее значение, чтобы его запомнить в другом свойстве.

Comment: Проще всего реализовать запоминание значения в сеттере свойства на стороне `c++`.

Comment: Конечно, проще. Но это тогда получается не проектирование, а написание костылей. Сеттер должен устанавливать значение и все. Его не должно волновать что там со значением потом происходит - запоминается ли оно, или еще что с ним делается.

Comment: А вы ожидаете найти какой-то готовый паттерн, в котором делается все тоже самое только под капотом? Чтобы знать предыдущее значение, его в любом должен кто-то помнить.

Answer (score 2):

А что если:

```
RibbonImage {
    property var previousDigit
    property var bufTargetDigit

    targetDigit: timeString.charAt(5)

    onTargetDigitChanged: {
        previousDigit = bufTargetDigit
        bufTargetDigit = targetDigit
    }   
}
```

Таким образом, `previousDigit` всегда равен предыдущему значению, а `bufTargetDigit = bufTargetDigit`, за исключением момента, когда `targetDigit` меняется.

Comment: Да, это правильное решение. Его обсудили вот здесь: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/13981618

Comment: @Xintrea а, ну ок. А то вопрос висит как нерешённый :)

Answer (score 0):

Желательно было бы увидеть пример и вашего кода, чтобы было понятно, что именно требуется.

Приведу пример, как можно организовать запоминание предыдущего цвета виджета.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Rectangle {

    id: root

    property color prev     // хранит предыдущий цвет
    property color tempc    // swap - переменная

    width: 200
    height: 200

    color: random_color()

    ColumnLayout {

        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
            text: "Change Color"

            onClicked: {
                prev_btn.enabled = true;
                root.prev = root.color;
                root.color = random_color();
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: prev_btn
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
            text: "Prev color"
            enabled: false

            onClicked: {
                root.tempc = root.color;
                root.color = root.prev;
                root.prev = root.tempc;
            }
        }
    }   

    function random_color() {
        return Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1)
    }
}
```

Не уверен, что это правильный путь. Запоминание значений свойств можно перенести и на `c++` сторону.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вопрос был в другом. Добавил пояснение к вопросу.